# Where is utouch in ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: multi-touch

I have recently upgraded to ubuntu 12.10 and utouch seems to be removed from my system and I am not able to reinstall it through apt-get. Where can I find it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I guess that [this isssue from touchegg](http://code.google.com/p/touchegg/issues/detail?id=169) will explain the situation a bit...

Answer (score 1):

[The utouch package has been renamed to GEIS](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1030937), in upstream. So to install it, you should look for the `geis` package.